# Compile-Time Check on AnyVal for Allocation?

Tags: scala

The Scala docs discuss [AnyVal](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

In the `When Allocation Is Necessary` section, it mentions:

```
case class P(val i: Int) extends AnyVal
val p = new P(3)
p match { // new P instantiated here
  case P(3) => println("Matched 3")
  case P(x) => println("Not 3")
}
```

Is it possible, at compile-time, to know whether an `AnyVal` requires allocation, i.e. to be put onto the heap rather than the stack?

Furthermore, I'd like to write the above code, and then, at compile-time, receive a warning that `p match {` results in allocation.

As I understand, allocation defeats the purpose of an `AnyVal`.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9504